# How to input key-value pairs into a constant mapping in a library in solidity?

Tags: solidity, mapping, library

How can I input key-value pairs into `foo`? Is there something like below that can be done?

```
library abc {
    mapping(int256 => int256) internal constant foo = {1: 10, 2: 20, ...};
    \\ rest of code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Constant Do not change

library Do not change

Comment: So you can't modify it

Comment: Thanks. I'm not trying to modify it but to set it as a constant. But how do I do that?